# Strange behaviour in the if statement

Tags: javascript, arrays, loops, if-statement, dom

I have a piece of code that is meant to hide table elements depending on given array. I am running loops to compare innerText of one of the cells and the given array.

However, my if statement is statement is acting weird, once i set the operator to `===` the operation is successful and table rows that match the array are hidden. But i need my if to hide the elements that are not a part of the array, so naturally I set my operator to `!==` but once i do it it just executes anyway and of course hides all of the elements in the table.

Any idea why this is happening here is the code:

```
var td1 = document.querySelectorAll("#course");
var rowss = document.querySelectorAll("#rows");

var courseNames1 = [td1.innerText];

var diff = _.difference(soretedArray, courseNames1)

console.log(diff);

for (var i = 0; i < rowss.length; i++) {
  for (var j = 0; j < diff.length; j++) {
    if (td1[i].innerText === diff[j]) { // if i set the logic operator to !== it hides all of the elements rather the ones that don't match
      console.log(rowss[i]);
      rowss[i].style.display = "none";
      break;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Sounds like you want to hide it when *all* of them match that predicate, not just the first one.

Comment: `var courseNames1 =[];` followed by `courseNames1 = td1.innerText` doesn't make any sense. Do you want `courseNames1` to be an array or not? (The assignment replaces the array with a string.)

Comment: Why "document.querySelectorAll("#course")" where ID should unique?

Comment: this is selecting all off the cells of the table

Comment: You still have `courseNames1` in your code. I think you should not have deleted the code for it.

Comment: ups...my fault.

Comment: any ideas??????

Comment: I think you want `var  courseNames1 = [td1.innerText];`

Comment: You stop the inner loop with a `break`, which is already in there.

Comment: `soretedArray` has a spelling error and is not defined in the code you show.

Comment: Its just an array filtered trough combo boxes its updated correctly and console outputs good outputs

Comment: if you do `console.dir(diff);` is the output satisfactory? I don't spot any more bugs in the code.

Comment: I don't understand `td1[i]` it doesn't make sense as you also have code `td1.innerText`. What does td1 contain? A single td or multiple?

Comment: td contains my table cells that im using to map on the array

Comment: its strange it only hides when it matches but not when the operator is !==,  then it hides them all..

Comment: But it seems you want to exclude `courseNames1` content from the `soretedArray`. Do you want to exclude all courses from the `soretedArray`?

Comment: I really dont need that function as the 'soretedArray' is already the one needed to map onto the table cells

Comment: Does every row have a corresponding course? Because I would expect otherwise tohave read this `td1[i].innerText` instead `rowss[i].innerText`

Comment: Yes they are unique values an apply onto each row. Console would output it correctly as well.

Answer (score 1):

I added the code as I have understood your request: You want the negation of "contains" to hide the element. This is as complete as possible based on the information you gave.

```
var soretedArray = [];//initialized elsewhere
var td1 = document.querySelectorAll("#course");
var rowss = document.querySelectorAll("#rows");

function tdContains(td) {
  for(var j= 0 ; j< soretedArray.length; j++){
      if(td.innerText === soretedArray[j]){
        return true;
      }
    }
    return false;
}

for(var i = 0 ; i < rowss.length; i++){
  if(!tdContains(td1[i])) {
      console.log(rowss[i]);
      rowss[i].style.display= "none";
  }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, works better now getting the required  elements to be hidden!